# One to one relationship in Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I'll try and put this as simply as possible but basically what I am trying to achieve is this.

There are two page types with a one to one relationship, car and owner.  I want to be able te be able to select an owner through a dropdown on the car page.  If an owner is already linked to another car I don't want it to appear in the dropdown.

I know that I'll need an if statement but I I'm finding it hard to puzzle out how it should go.  I followed this [tutorial](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dynamically-generating-a-dropdown-list/) to create the dropdown and it worked quite well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in case you feel like the proposed solutions seem overly complex for a rather simple task - you are not alone :) - see this discussion of core developers on the issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/silverstripe-dev/d1VH-NT8qcc/gJNPr_WCyvwJ%5B1-25%5D

Comment: I can't seem to open that link @schellmax.  It comes up blank. I'm really interested in reading it though.

Comment: oops, please try this one: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/silverstripe-dev/d1VH-NT8qcc/discussion (you need to have a google account though as it's on google groups)

Comment: Brilliant, worked that time.  Thanks a mill.  It's nice to have helpful people like you to answer my newbie questions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the function that gives you the dropdown values. Your `DataObject::get()` call 
 can have a filter for the second argument. Simply select all owners that have a CarID of 0.

So, from the tutorial you provided, you can use this modified code:

```
new DropdownField(
    'OwnerID',
    'Please choose an owner',
    Dataobject::get("Owner","CarID='0'")->map("ID", "Title", "Please Select")
);
```

**2 things to note:**

- This assumes your DataObjects are called `Car` and `Owner` (change as necessary, but keep the ID at the end of the name as it is written above)
- This may not work depending how you set up the relationships with the `$has_one` assignments on your DataObjects. If there is no `CarID` field on the `Owner` table, then this code won't help you (you may have it set up vice-versa). In that case, you'll have to create a function that loops through all cars, and then removes the DataObjects from that DataObjectSet that have an `OwnerID` of 0. Add a comment if this isn't making sense.

Comment: +1 for a valid approach, but i think you're missing the fact that even though there might be a CarID field on the Owner table, it won't ever get updated and will always have a value of 0; so some DataObjectSet fumbling as you mention can't be avoided

Comment: Yes that makes sense to me.  I will try to implement it and let you know how I get on.  +1 for really good answer by the way.

Comment: I have hit a slight stumbling block now. The owner table I am using is actually registered users for the site (Member table) and so I can't use this.  Can I do something like  Dataobject::get("Owner", "Car.OwnerID='0'")?

Comment: See the Relation filters in the [Data Model docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel)... something like `$members = Member::get()->filter(array(
    'Car.ID' => '0'
));` (untested).

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin Smith' answer is perfectly valid for the dropdown you were asking for, just wanted to point to another approach: instead of taking care of the one-to-one relation yourself, there's the 'HasOneComplexTableField' handling this for you.

use the following code for your Car class:

```
class Car extends Page {
    public static $has_one = array(
        'Owner' => 'Owner'
    );
    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $tablefield = new HasOneComplexTableField(
            $this,
            'Owner',
            'Owner',
            array(
                'Title' => 'Title'
            )
        );
        $tablefield->setParentClass('Car');
        $tablefield->setOneToOne();
        $tablefield->setPermissions(array());
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Owner', $tablefield);
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

note the 'setOneToOne()' call, telling the tablefield to only let you select Owners which aren't already selected on another car.

you'll find more information on this in the silverstripe tutorial: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/5-dataobject-relationship-management

Comment: Another really good approach.  I tried this tutorial not long ago actually.  I just thought the way it was laid out wouldn't be ideal for my users. I will give it another look if I can't get my dropdown to work the way I want.  Many thanks.